# How should I fix the error "more '%' conversions than data arguments"?

Tags: c

The code is supposed to converts the user's input(amount of change) into the number of coins they will receive and print it:

```
float dollars;
do
{
   dollars = get_float("Change owed:");
}
while (dollars <= 0);

int cents = round(dollars * 100);
int coins;

for (coins = 0; cents > 0; coins++)
{
    if (cents >= 25)
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
    }
    else if (cents < 25 && cents>=10)
    {
        cents = cents - 10;
    }
    else if (cents < 10 && cents >= 5)
    {
        cents = cents - 5;
    }
    else if (cents < 5 && cents >= 1)
    {
        cents = cents - 1;
    }
}
printf("%i coins, coins\n");
```

but i am getting this error

```
cash.c:37:31: error: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Werror,-Wformat]
printf("you will receive %i coins, coins\n");
                         ~^
```

Comment: By changing `printf("%i coins, coins\n");` to `printf("%i coins\n", coins);`

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem you are getting: just a comment on the coding.  Your checks for < 25, < 10 and < 5 are redundant because of previous conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bad calling to `printf` function. one more thing for `int` data tpe you should use the `%d` conversion/format specifier. `%i` format specifier is for Unsigned integer data type but your coins is signed integer so use `%d` or change the coins to be unsigned int.

Your bad call:

> ```
> printf("%i coins, coins\n");
> ```

`'\n'` is part of the string format:

```
printf("%d coins\n", coins);
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much

Comment: BTW no problem with `%i`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: @Hadi - glad to help. please vote up and  accept my answer (push the grey V nearby the answer start). shokran :-)!

Comment: `%i` is the same as `%d`; both are for `int` arguments, per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8. `%u` is for an `unsigned int`.